# Codeigniter pagination not showing content on page 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, pagination

i am searching for 2 days now but still no luck. my problem with my CodeIgniter Pagination is i have set my controller to show 1 data per page i have 2 data which means i have the 1,2 pagination. the [1] page is currently showing the correct data, but when i try to click [2] it still shows the data from the [1] page plus the url is page=1.

here is my **Controller**

```html
class Campaign extends CI_Controller
{
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->model('campaign_model');
$this->load->database();
$this->load->library('pagination');
}

function index() {
$this->load->view('campaign_view');
}

function submit() {
$this->form_validation->set_rules('campaignName', 'Campaign Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[ch_campaigns.c_campaign_name]');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
echo validation_errors();
} else {
$campaignName = $this->input->post('campaignName');

$data = array (
'c_campaign_name' => $campaignName
);

$this->db->insert('ch_campaigns', $data);

echo "YES";
}
}

public function campaigns() {

$data = array();

//pagination settings
$config['base_url'] = site_url('campaigns');
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('ch_campaigns');
$config['per_page'] = "1";
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
$config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

//config for bootstrap pagination class integration
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

//call the model function to get the department data
$data['campaignlist'] = $this->campaign_model->get_campaign_list($config["per_page"], $data['page']);           
//$data['campaignInfo'] = $this->campaign_model->get_campaign_list();
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

//load the department_view
//print var_export($data, true);
$this->load->view('campaign_view',$data);
}
}
```

here is my **Model**

```html
public function __construct() {
parent::__construct();
}

public function get_campaign_list($limit, $start) {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('ch_campaigns');
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);

$query = $this->db->get();

if($query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
$data[] = $row;
}

return $data;
}

return false;
}
}
```

lastly my **Views**

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Campaign Name</th>
<th>Owner</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>End Date</th>
<th>Total Leads</th>
<th> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($campaignlist as $list) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $list->c_campaign_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $list->c_customer_name; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $list->c_status; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $list->c_start_date; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $list->c_end_date; ?></td>
<td></td>
<td><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div class="main-container-footer text-center">
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? Right now I'm facing the same problem. So please share your answer if you are done with it :) Thanks

Comment: No, but I am using Data Tables now.